# Как настроить Post-processing volumes через скрипт?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я делаю игру на юнити и столкнулась с такой проблемой как Post-processing volumes. В иеррархии есть объект Post-processing volumes, он появился сам при создании и мне надо сделать так чтобы при переходе на сцену с индексом 2 в компоненте Color Adjustments включалась галочка на компоненте Saturation как мне сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Для получения компонента Post Process Volume используется `GameObject.GetComponent<PostProcessVolume>();`
Далее обращайтесь к нужным вам переменным.

[Документация Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@3.0/manual/Quick-start.html)

Comment: А никакие доп. библиотеки не надо подключать? Просто взять и в Update написать?

Comment: Боже, зачем в Update? Какие библиотеки? Вы точно разработчик?

Comment: Пожалуйста прочитайте заново мой вопрос. GetActiveScene лучше будет работать в Update или я не прав? Мне кажется это вы не разработчик так как вы не знаете что например using UnityEngine, using System и т.д. являются библиотеками.

Comment: И я проверил ваш способ и он не работает

Comment: Я прочитал вопрос и не увидел ничего про GetActiveScene. Вы говорили, что вам нужно изменить переменную в Post Processing Volume. Я написал вам, как это сделать, а вы мне начинаете про библиотеки и GetActiveScene.

Comment: GetComponent<>(); в update не вызывают. Это извращение.

Comment: `И я проверил ваш способ и он не работает` Что вы проверили? Я скинул вам код, которым пользуются для получения компонента все нормальные разработчики. Он работает